# how to resolve border-radius property issue in all versions of browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am new to CSS i have written the CSS for my home page,for that i have used border-radius property it is working fine on all the browsers except IE 6 to IE-8.Hi, I want to write code that will render  border-radius property for all versions of all browsers. can any one help me in how to write generic code for all versions and all browsers?
 thanks in advance.

Comment: on this earth who is using IE6 in 2014 :P

Comment: @Sachin I think you mean. On this earth who is using IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border-radius property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera, because it is CSS3 property.
so, you could use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)

first check this demo in IE 8 and download it from [here](http://css3pie.com/download/)
write your css rule like this

```
 #myAwesomeElement {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);
}
```

note: added `behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);` in the above rule. within url() you need to specify your PIE.htc file location

You can see some more reference from [here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/use-css3-pie-to-modernize-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ to support border radius. but you need to add a javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Border-radius is not supported in IE 8 and below. You can't use that property in IE 8 and below

Comment: This is not an answer. According to the question, author is aware of this fact.

Answer (score 0):

IE versions 8 and below does not support border-radius.

Comment: downvoter: care to explain? nothing wrong with this answer!